# Create a column with one of two variables based on another columns character

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, pipe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| location | sample_year | mean |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ann Lake | 2003 | 22 |
| Bird Lake | 2003 | 22 |
| Tree Lake | 2003 | 22 |
| Ann River | 2003 | 22 |
| Tim River | 2003 | 22 |
| Dog River | 2003 | 22 |
| Apple River | 2003 | 22 |

I want to create a new column specifying location type if its a river or lake:

| location | sample_year | mean | location_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ann Lake | 2003 | 22 | lake |
| Bird Lake | 2003 | 22 | lake |
| Tree Lake | 2003 | 22 | lake |
| Ann River | 2003 | 22 | river |
| Tim River | 2003 | 22 | river |
| Dog River | 2003 | 22 | river |
| Apple River | 2003 | 22 | river |

I've tried this to no avail:

```
df%>%
  mutate(location_type = ifelse(location(contains("River"), "river", "lake")))
```

Is there a way to do this with a dplyr pipe?

Comment: is `location(...)` an attempt to access the column named `location`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `stringr`'s `str_detect()` function here.

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(location_type = ifelse(str_detect(location, "River"), "river", "lake"))
```